# ARKit – Body Tracking inaccuracy

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, mo-cap

I am having an issue with accuracy of body tracking. I am visualising joints of body with objects. In picture where I stand straight and still it works fine and you can see position of knee, ankle and toes joints. In next images (from left to right) in different angles and different leg positions it's not very accurate.

[image]

My question is – if Apple's body tracking with Lidar is capable of tracking these joints correctly and my solution isn't good, or currently it's not precise enough to do this. And if it is possible, how can I improve accuracy.
I need to capture movement of these joints during the walk.
In this same configuration tracking of (for example) hands works good enough.

Answer (score 0):

ARKit's and RealityKit's `Body Motion Capture` really takes advantage when you track body using a device with a LiDAR Scanner. And Apple engineers explicitly say about it in [Advanced Scene Understanding in AR](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/609) video (time: 1:30). But there's no guarantee that LiDAR will help you improve a quality of MoCap in your particular case. The only advice – just try it.

Comment: I'm using iPad which has LiDAR. So it is possible that currently it might not be possible to track this kind of movement accurately?

Comment: Apple says: `Yes`. But some developers say: `...not always...`